# Jquery Mobile - ListView on Click Color

Tags: jquery-mobile

For Jquery Mobile, I have a ListView. I do not have any theme for the ListView. It is the normal grey color.

On MouseOver of a listitem, I like it to have the blue that comes with

```
     theme-b.
```

I like to do it only for mouseover.

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into the jQuery Mobile theme CSS and copy the `.ui-btn-hover-a` code into the `.ui-btn-hover-c` declaration(s). Basically just copy the code you want and use it to overwrite the "c" swatch class (or whatever swatch you want to use).

I actually copy the code from `.ui-btn-up-*` to the `.ui-btn-hover-*` declarations so there isn't a "hover" state (the "hover" and "up" states are the same so nothing has to be redrawn when the "hover" class is added to an element). This helps improve performance, especially when you have a long list that the user has to scroll.